# View-only, web-based NX viewer/client for slick Linux screen-sharing, presentations

Tags: linux, vnc, nx

I currently share my screen for presentations using VNC, since it's easy to share with anyone who has little more than a web browser with noVNC.

Is there a similar viewer (HTML5, Flash, or - as a last resort - Java) that uses the faster NX protocol?  The only NX clients I can find today are "full" clients, which require a download/install and have no view-only mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NoMachine's NX Web Companion](http://www.nomachine.com/products.php). It is free and provides a Java applet that downloads (only the first time) all the components you need from the applet. Then the NoMachine NX client is executed. It is installable on your server (remote machine to view). It is not only-view, but it is the best approach I know.